# Using SendGrid Inbound Parse Webook with Un-verified SSL certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, sendgrid

My Heroku Rails Production app is secured via an SSL certificate. For my staging environment, however, I rely on a self-signed certificate.

When using SendGrid's inbound parse webhook, it attempts to parse an email and `POST` to an endpoint in my app for processing.

On staging all the requests are failing because

```
REASON500 Can't connect to staging.example.co:443 (certificate verify failed)
```

Is there a way to circumvent this, similar to the `-k` flag with `curl` that lets you ignore SSL with an insecure connection

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Not explicitly. The best I could do was instead of having it `POST` to my staging app, I had it `POST` to an app running on my local machine, so i could test it out in development. I did that by using `ngrok`, which is a tool that gives you a public URL endpoint that connects to your machine. The free version requires you to generate a new url each time so it was slightly cumbersome, but the paid version gives you a fixed URL